# Symfony2 How to get foreign key from database

Tags: forms, entity-framework, symfony

I have entity Patients with a field

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Surgery\LoginBundle\Entity\User" , mappedBy="patient")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 protected $user;
```

I want to get foreign key from Patiens ,so I created that query

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT p.user_id FROM SurgeryPatientBundle:Patients p WHERE p.user =5 ');
```

I get this error

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 9 near 'user_id FROM': Error: Class Surgery\PatientBundle\Entity\Patients has no field or association named user_id '
```

My question it's  can I get to that field without create JOIN ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u.id FROM SurgeryPatientBundle:Patients p JOIN p.user u WHERE p.user =5')
```

or

```
$patient = $em->getRepository('SurgeryPatientBundle:Patients')->findOneBy(array('user' => 5));
$user = $patient->getUser()->getId();
```

Comment: First query working but I writed how to get to this value without create JOIN query, I know it works with JOIN , but I have this value in database or this only relation with User table. Dzięki za odpowiedź ;D

Answer (score 0):

p.user.id should do the job.

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT p.user.id FROM SurgeryPatientBundle:Patients p WHERE p.user =5 ');
```

Remember to think in terms of objects and not database column names.  I'm assuming that user has a getId() method on it.

```
echo $query->getQuery()->getSQL();  // Handy for debugging
```

I suspect that you won't find the id to be all the useful.  Probably need to use $em->createPartialReference() to get yourself a user object that can be used in other relations.

And make sure you do something like:

```
$query->getQuery()->getScalerResult();
```

Comment: If I changed to p.user.id I get this error Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got '.'. And yes I have getId() method

Comment: p.user = 5?  Is the 5 supposed to be user with an id of 5?

Comment: p.user 5 is a number of foreign key , this query works when I Select for example only lastname SELECT p.lastname or everything , but I don't know how to get to from query, in my view this code patients.user.id works

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function getBaseExportQuery()
{
  return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
              ->getQuery()
              ->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_INCLUDE_META_COLUMNS, true)
              ->getArrayResult();

}
```